# Can't set StatusBar color with setStatusBarColor if FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS is used

Tags: android, window, statusbar

I'm trying to draw a layout behind the NavigationBar. To do this I set `FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS` as follows:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

This indeed causes the layout to be drawn behind the NavigationBar, but it also sets the StatusBar background color to white/transparent.
Changing the StatusBar color using `getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.RED);` has no effect.

I'm all the work dynamically and can't use and styling .xml files.
Is this a known behavior of `FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
 getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);`

Also [check this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window#setStatusBarColor(int))